# If $(A\times B)\cup (B\times A) = C\times C$ then $A = B = C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need to prove that there exists C for which :

$$(A \times B) \cup (B \times A) = C \times C \Longrightarrow A = B = C$$

This is a very simple question, which I understand, but I'm having difficulties to prove it in a written form.

Any help is appreciated =)

Comment: Do you need to prove it for _all_ $C$, or that there exists a particular $C$? If it's the latter, then the simplest $C$ you can imagine certainly satisfies it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT:**

Show that if $A\neq B$ then there is no $C$ such that $A\times B\cup B\times A=C\times C$. If $a\in A\setminus B$, what can you say about the pair $(a,a)$ with respect to this union?

Comment: Yeah thanks, managed to prove it, was thinking too much into it like always =)