# If there are sets $C$ and $D$ satisfying $(A\times B)\cup (B\times A)=C\times D,$ then $A=B=C=D.$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Suppose $A$ and $B$ are nonempty sets. If there are sets $C$ and $D$ satisfying $(A\times B)\cup (B\times A)=C\times D,$ then $A=B=C=D.$

**My attempt:**

In this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1024579/721644) it has been shown that $(A\times B)\cup (B\times A)=C\times C\implies A=B=C,$ so I tried to argue $C=D$ necessarily.

Since $A$ and $B$ are both nonempty, so are $A\times B$ and $B\times A$ and in turn, their union $C\times D,$ which implies $C$ and $D$ are nonempty, too.
Let $c\in C$ be arbitrary. Then $(c,d)\in C\times D$ for any $d\in D,$ so $(c,d)\in A\times B$ or $(c,d)\in B\times A.$ Either way, $(d,c)\in C\times D\implies c\in D.$ Since $c\in C$ was arbitrary, $C\subseteq D$ and I would similarly argue that $D\subseteq C,$ which would yield $C=D.$

Now, as (I hope) $C=D,$ the claim follows from the linked result.

Comment: How does $(d,c)\in C\times D$ follow from $(c,d)\in A\times B\vee (c,d)\in B\times A$? I think you should write that out explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

There's a really nice geometric intuition for the problem. Let us first assume that $A=\{0,1,2\},B=\{0,1,2,3,4\}$. Then, the cartesian product contains points with integer coordinates in the Cartesian plane in the shape of a rectangle. The visualization is this:

[image: AxB]

($A\times B$)

[image: BxA]

($B\times A$)

By the same token, $C\times D$ must also be a rectangle, but $(A\times B) \cup (B\times A) = C\times D$, hence $(A\times B) \cup (B\times A)$ needs to be a rectangle. However, it is evidently not:

[image]

($(A\times B) \cup (B\times A)$)

It turns out that $(A\times B) \cup (B\times A)$ is only ever a rectangle if it is a square, or equivalently, $A=B$. Thus, $$(A\times A) \cup (A\times A) = C\times D= A\times A,$$ so $C=D=A(=B)$.

Okay, cool, but perhaps you are looking for a more "set-theoretic" proof. Luckily for us the geometric intuition generalizes well: Let $A,B$ now be arbitrary. We first assume $A\neq B$ and try to find a contradiction. Indeed, we notice that both $C$ and $D$ must contain every element of $A$ and $B$ from $(A\times B) \cup (B\times A) = C\times D$. The geometric intuition tells us to find an element in the missing piece of "the square". Without loss of generality we assume that $B\backslash A$ is nonempty, hence there is an element $x\in B\backslash A$. We note that $x\in B$ so $x\in C$ and $x\in D$. Thus, $(x,x)$ is in $C\times D$. However, $x$ is definitely not in $A$, so $(x,x)$ ISN'T in $(A\times B)$ nor in $(B\times A)$, so it isn't in $(A\times B) \cup (B\times A)$. This contradicts $(A\times B) \cup (B\times A) = C\times D$.

It must therefore be necessary that $A=B$, wherein $A\times A=C\times D$, i.e, $A=B=C=D$.

$x\in B\backslash A$ in the original example can be $3$ or $4$. $(3,3)$ and $(4,4)$ do correspond precisely to missing pieces in the square:

[image]

(highlighted in red.)